# Error: binding to reference of type discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, eclipse, binding, linked-list

I am so sorry, I know this has been asked before, but even if I tried reading all the other answers to similar questions I can't understand my error.
I am using Eclipse, I am programming in C++ and I am trying to make a **linked list** using templates.

I am using a **node class** that will be useful for my linked list, and I have this function specification:

```
template <class item>
void list_insert(node<item>*& head, const item&e);
```

Allright. I want to use this function SO in my **list class** I can have this:

```
template <class item>
class list{
public:
    list(){head=NULL;}

    void set_head(node<item>*h){head=h;}
    node<item>*& get_head(){return head;}
    const node<item>* get_head()const{return head;}

    bool empty()const{return head==NULL;} // is the list empty?

    void insert(const item&e){list_insert(head,e);} //ERROR GETS HERE!
    void print(); // print the list clockwise
    void printback(); //print it counterclockwise

private:
    node<item>* head;
};
```

I do that so I can implement list_insert like this:

```
template <class item>
void list_insert(node<item>*& head, const item& e){
    head= new node<item>(e,head);
}
```

Now, in this last piece of code I get this error:

**error: binding 'const int' to reference of type 'int&' discards qualifiers**

I have read that basically the compiler is telling me ''ehi, if you do that, the const condition you wanted will be violated, so I give you an error'', allright, but still I don't understand the actuall error, or, anyway, what is the reasoning behind it.

Also because I am supposed to do a counterclockwise insert function too, but I am having troubles with the clockwise actually, so I am pretty stuck.

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: I am so sorry I did not provide actual example of what I am doing.
Basically, I am trying to make a linked list - simply and basic for my exam.

My linked-list is basically a stack made of nodes. Nodes are the component of my list, that are made of a data part and a link to the next node part:

```
template <class item>
class node{
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    nodo(item & d=item(), nodo*l=NULL){
        data=d;
        link=l;
    }

    //GET E SET METHODS
    void set_data(item& d){data=d;}
    void set_link(node*l){link=l;}

    item& get_data(){return data;}
    const item& get_data()const{return data;}
    node*& get_link(){return link;}
    const node* get_link()const{return link;}

private:
    item data;
    node* link;
};
```

Now, as said my list is made of nodes and in the private part I declared a pointer to the head of the list.

```
 node<item>* head;
```

That is the example of this code-- and then the problem occurs as I wrote before.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What is the problem?

Comment: See the declaration of the node's constructor.

Comment: The problem is that I used <item> as <int> in my main, but for every datatype I use, the function keeps having a binding problem with the const declaration. As the compiler says, it is a binding problem, but I can't understand it since I actually put the variables with reasoning. And the error keeps showing up in the implementation of my list_insert function.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE. What's "node"? -- [mcve]

Comment: Ahh, sorry, my bad. I edited the post out. Is it better?

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of `node` you should pass `item` by const-reference (and there is some typo, perhaps a copy+paste error in your `node` class.

```
class node{
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    node(item const & d=item(), node*l=0)
        : data(d), link(l) // prefer initializer list here
    { }
    //...
```

Comment: ohmygoditworked. Yes, sorry, the typo was because of a copy+paste error, I am so sorry, but it actually worked. I actually did not think about the constructor, I have to be honest, I was obsessed with the implementation of my function. And that is why I actually realized too late that the constructor had some problems, I am so sorry.

Thank you so much for the help, anyway!